# Passing output of a command as positional parameter to script file in Linux shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to pass the output of a command as positional parameter to a script file. I am running the command below:

```
whois -h 192.168.0.13 google.com | grep -e Domain\ Name
```

That command will give me a "name". What I want to do is pass that output again to a shell script file as positional parameter.

my-file.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#My First Script

if [ $1 == "my-domain-name" ]; then
   echo "It is ok"
   exit 1
fi
```

So, basically what I want to do is something like this:

```
whois -h 192.168.0.13 google.com | grep -e Domain\ Name | -here pass the Name to my-file.sh and run that file
```

Comment: A non-zero exit code indicates an error or non-successful condition of some type. Use `exit 0` if it is OK.

Comment: Hi Wai. I notice that, again, this post was rather chatty, featuring more please-halp-me begging and pleading, now edited out by @Inian. I made a note of that style on your prior questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46590657) and [here (deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46778203). As you know, we encourage brevity and technical writing on Stack Overflow. Could I trouble you this time to reply, to acknowledge that you have seen my request? Thank you.

Comment: FYI, it would more accurately be `[ "$1" = my-domain-name ]`. A constant string that has no spaces or wildcard characters doesn't need quotes; a parameter expansion *always* needs quotes; and `==` isn't guaranteed to work in `[ ]` with all shells, whereas `=` is mandated by the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define a new function to check the `whois` output and use the return string in the if condition as below. This way you can avoid the multi-level pipeline while executing the script and rather just control it via a simple function.

```
get_whois_domainName() {
    whois -h 192.168.0.13 google.com | grep -e Domain\ Name
}

if [ "$(get_whois_domainName)" = "my-domain-name" ]; then
   echo "It is ok"
   exit 0
fi
```

But if you still want to pass via the command line, do

```
my-file.sh "$(whois -h 192.168.0.13 google.com | grep -e Domain\ Name)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to do that:

```
my-file.sh "$(whois -h 192.168.0.13 google.com | grep -e Domain\ Name)"
```

It is more straightforward to read than using a pipe and `xargs`, which is another working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` to select a proper column from the output. Then use `xargs` to pass its output as an argument to your script.

```
whois google.com | grep -e Domain\ Name | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs bash ./test.sh
```

Comment: Why two separate tools? `awk '/Domain Name/ { print $3 }'`